# I can't find a setting to disable WINS in Network settings

Tags: macos, network, security

In my Network settings under WINS I have the NetBios name (elly) that I would like to disable (kill).

The message shows that the "elly"is currently been used ?

By whom, for what ?

There a bunch of messages in the Console with for example elly.local WindowServer ?? what server ? I do not have one ?

My search on Google and here did not help.

I tried deleting the NetBios name, but it comes back!

Also tried the without success!

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.netbiosd.plist
```

I have no local network, nor any workgroup set up, just a lone wifi connection to the world.

Running Hostname in Terminal shows "Elly.Local"

I would not mind using Terminal to kill it, but I'm just wondering whether there's any UI-based way to just turn off all of this stuff. I am not a big fan of running services I'm not using.

MBA 10.8.4

Comment: Added the flag Security, because being concerned not to run services you don't control is a plain legitimate security improvment.

Comment: I don't have an answer yet for your query, but I did want to clarify something. In your question, you reference WindowServer as if it is a Microsoft Windows Server, it appears. However, WindowServer is an element of OS X (AppKit, HIToolbox, etc.) See link below for more about WindowServer.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794-CH1-SUBSECTION14

Answer (score 5):

I didn't find any way through the GUI (on Snow Leopard, Lion, Mountain Lion, Mavericks, Yosemite, El Capitan & Sierra).

On the other hand the following receipe is stopping `netbiosd`.
In a `Terminal` or an `xterm` type:

```
% ps ax | grep [/]netbios
  122   ??  SNs    1:52.41 /usr/sbin/netbiosd
% /usr/bin/sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.netbiosd.plist
Password:
% ps ax | grep [/]netbios
%
```

The second `ps` command shouldn't output anything. This is normal and
means that there isn't anymore any `netbiosd` running.

Another way to check that `netbiosd` isn't anymore chating continuously on all your network interfaces is to use `tcpdump` for a full 5 minutes:

```
% /usr/bin/sudo tcpdump -i en0 host elly.local udp port netbios-ns
[...]
^C
0 packets captured
nnnnnn packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
% /usr/bin/sudo tcpdump -i en1 host elly.local udp port netbios-ns
[...]
^C
0 packets captured
mmmmmm packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
%
```

These 2 commands should say exactly `0 packets captured` otherwise something is leaking.

Comment: If with time and experience increasing you find any nicer way, please post it. I'm interested too :).

Comment: This worked for macOS Sierra: `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.netbiosd.plist`

Comment: → bassplayer7: thank you for this validation on actual version :).

Answer (score 0):

`sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.netbiosd.plist`

Worked for my 2012 Mac Mini with El Capitan. Restarted twice and no `netbiosd` in Activity Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, Apple has a support article dealing with this here:

[How to disable SMB 1 or NetBIOS in macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211927)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.