# What's netbiosd? I must block netbiosd?

Tags: macos, firewall

I was asked to block netbiosd, but do not know what is. I must to block all connections from netbiosd?

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81751/should-i-block-incoming-connections-from-netbiosd

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple's netbiosd man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/netbiosd.8.html):

> netbiosd is responsible for interacting with NetBIOS networks.  netbiosd registers and defends one or more NetBIOS name, depending on the set of configured services. It also browses and scavenges names from the NetBIOS network, making them available to the system through mDNSResponder.

Simply put, no, `netbiosd` is a perfectly safe daemon included in OS X by Apple.